# Why does the OneDrive js Picker in Edge go back to the redirect URI instead of showing the files?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, onedrive

I have copied the sample code from the [OneDrive Picker JS example](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm) to [my playground site](https://playground.rubiconatlas.org/onedrive.html), replaced the clientId with mine, and then when trying it in MS Edge, the new window will open. After signing in, it displays the original page instead of the picker. Why isn't it showing the picker? In all other major browsers (including IE 11) it shows the picker...

I tried toggling the option *Allow Implicit Flow* in the App registration page but that didn't help.

[image]

### Update 9/23/2016

I downloaded the sample code to my site, pasted in my clientId and loaded it in Edge - the issue still persists. This leads me to believe it is an issue with the app registration. In the app registration I see that there are options for selecting **Microsoft Graph Permissions** - both **Delegated Permissions** and **Application Permissions** - I tried adding *Files.Read* and then *Files.Read.All* but neither improved the situation. Is there another setting in the registration I should configure?

### Update 10/3/2016

I noticed the other day that the browser requirement for Edge is version 25+ and I had version 20. I spent a few hours installing non-critical updates to the OS, which updated Edge to version 38. Now when I try the [sample code on my playground site](https://playground.rubiconatlas.org/onedriveExample.html) I see the new window open, the main window will refresh within a few seconds and after I login in the new window, it stalls on [this oauth2 authorize url](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fplayground.rubiconatlas.org%2Fonedrive.html&client_id=8fc7a783-01a0-4ecb-897b-4b09770ec38f&scope=profile%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FFiles.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read&response_mode=fragment&state=aad_login&nonce=Guzqc&response_type=id_token+token).

Comment: i am facing some issue related to this sdk can u help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251974/how-to-handle-multiple-tenants-with-onedrive-picker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it was a Windows 10 network group policy that was blocking this.