# how to handle multiple tenants with onedrive picker

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I am facing a problem with onedrive picker with https://js.live.net/v5.0/OneDrive.js

I have different redirect url's like

http://dev.example.com

http://dev1.example.com

by giving these two urls i am facing problem like this
[image: unique domain]

when i give redirect url it is not working.[image: onedrive picker]

and i tried using https://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js while i am using this one in pop only the redirect url is loading and redirecting and closing the pop up i am not getting the call back success

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v5.0/OneDrive.js" id="onedrive-js" client-id="APP_ID"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
      function launchOneDriveSaver(){
var saverOptions = {
      success: function(files){
            console.log(files);
      },
     progress: function(p) {
    // upload is progressing
    },
    cancel: function(){
    // upload was cancelled
   },
   error: function(e) {
  // an error occured
  }

        OneDrive.save(saverOptions);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: could you edit your post to include [the options](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm#picker-options) passed to `OneDrive.open()` (hiding the clientId of course)?

Comment: hey i edited my code can you check now

Comment: I tried with version SDK [version 5](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v5/javascript-picker-saver.htm) and [version 7](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-save.htm) and see errors in both - even the demo on the version 7 page throws an error... We might have to file an issue with MS...

Comment: the straight forward way is using the picker SDK http://dev.example.com and iframe it on the domain http://dev1.example.com.

Comment: can you give an example overview for that using fiddle / plunker

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding root domain? Try this order :

```
http://example.com
http://dev.example.com
http://dev1.example.com
```

Comment: A bit more explanation here might help StackOverflow users.